# Converting an infinite summation to an integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

The expression that I have is,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{n^2 + j} + \frac{1}{n^2 - j}\right).$$

Original expression:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=-n}^n \left(\frac{1}{n^2 - j}\right).$$

I have prove that this summation is equal to '2'

Comment: Summation index j instead of i?

Comment: Please verify your expression:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2+j}\leq (n+1)\frac{1}{n^2}\to 0$$
and the same for the second term.

Comment: what is that for?
the series was given to be convergent

Comment: Alright so the original series was written in a slightly different way , I shall put it in

Comment: the lower and upper limit of the summation are the same thing

Comment: that was an error, I fixed that

the second summation is the original one and the the limits are  from -n to n

Comment: Nice that you tried "Taylor expanding the root". But which root ?

Comment: oh. I fogot to put a root ...

I'll make a new question

Comment: I put the correct question here

apologies to all

on the bright side, we got a completely different question answered

Comment: [corrected question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3553579/147357)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that:

$$\frac{-\left(n+1\right)}{n^{2}}=-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{j=0}^{n}1\le\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{n^{2}+j}-\frac{1}{n^{2}-j}\right]\le\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{j=0}^{n}1=\frac{n+1}{n^{2}}$$

Squeezing the both sides implies the limits is $0$

Comment: @DDD4C4U: this answer also says that the series is convergent !

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 0.

All terms are at most $1/(n^2-n)$.
Since there are $2n+2$ of them,
the sum is at most
$(2n+2)/(n^2-n)
\to 0$ as
$n \to \infty$.

Comment: @DDD4C4U: this answer also says that the series is convergent !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten a factor $n$ :

$$\frac{n}{n²+j}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{j}{n(n²+j)}$$ and for $0\leq j\leq n$ we have
 $$\frac{j}{n(n²+j)}\leq \frac{n}{n(n²)}=\frac{1}{n^2}$$. Now show that $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{n}{n²+j}\to 1$$ and  do the same for the second term, to finally show that $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}(\frac{n}{n²+j}+\frac{n}{n²-j}) \to 2$$